# Context.getResources() returns null while startActivity(Intent) runs

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Did some major refactoring on my codebase (mostly moving classes into new packages) recently and now I'm getting errors when trying to start my NavigationDrawer activity after a user login.

DistributorLogin runs an asynctask to validate the user's credentials and returns with a Distributor object that is passed as an extra with the Intent that starts the NavigationDrawer. At some point after startActivity(Intent) runs, a call to Context.getResources() occurs while setting up the activity. It appears that the resources object is returned as null. Some devices have this error occur in ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(int) and I've also seen it happen in Window.getDefaultFeatures(Context) while trying to retrieve a boolean. This problem only occurs while trying to start the NavDrawer activity. Other activities appear to start just fine. NavDrawer's onCreate() is never called.

**DistributorLogin.activity**

```
@Override
public void distributorAuthenticationFinished(Distributor output) {

try {
        //Only continue if a valid Distributor object was received
        if (output != null) {

            String currentLanguage = "ENG";
            DistributorSettings distributorSettings = output.getDistributorSettings();
            if (distributorSettings != null) {
                String homeCountry = distributorSettings.getHomeCountry();
                currentLanguage = distributorSettings.getCurrentLanguage();
                Content.getInstance().setCurrentLocale(homeCountry, currentLanguage);
                writeContentDocs(homeCountry, currentLanguage, false);
                writeAllSupportedLanguageDocs();
            }

            //Clear UI element values
            etxt_name.setText("");
            etxt_password.setText("");

            //Attempt to register a new device token if one is not already saved.
            Intent tokenIntent = IntentCreator.getTokenRegistrationIntent(this, RegistrationTokenIntentService.CREATE_NEW_IF_NONE_EXISTS,
                    Distributor.distributorId, Distributor.homeCountry, currentLanguage);
            startService(tokenIntent);

            // Start the main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavDrawer.class);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.cb_parameter_distributor), output);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error starting nav drawer activity.", e);
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<manifest
    package="com.marketamerica.android.unfranchiseprospecting"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:name=".models.Ufp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.DistributorLogin"
            android:label="@string/app_name_acronym"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.NavDrawer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nav_drawer"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**NavDrawer**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ufpTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ufp_2-0.ttf");

    isTablet = Ufp.getIsTablet();

    // Get application resources
    resources = this.getResources();

    // Define our sharedPreferences and editor objects
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(resources.getString(R.string.ma_content_shared_prefs_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    checkAndResetSharedPrefsIfNecessary();


    // Set the initial fragmentState
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentState = FragmentState.viewable;
        sharedPreferencesEditor.putString("fragmentState", "viewable");
        sharedPreferencesEditor.apply();
    } else {
        shouldRestoreMediaDetail = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(getString(R.string.media_detail_arg_key));
    }


    restoreSelectedProspectId(sharedPreferences);

    if (!selectedProspectId.equals("")) {
        prospectDetails = repository.get(getString(R.string.cb_parameter_prospect_doc_prefix) + selectedProspectId, ProspectDetails.class);
    }

    // Assign our Distributor object from CB
    distributor = (Distributor) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(getString(R.string.cb_parameter_distributor));

    // ThreadPoolExecutors responsible for updating prospectDetailsArrayList and timelineItemArrayList
    detailsThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    timelineThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());;
    startProspectDetailsLiveQuery();
    startTimelineLiveQuery();

    // Instantiate fragmentManager
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    // Set up our content views and layouts
    if (!isTablet) { // Handset layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);
        container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        setupFloatingActionButton();
        setUpToolbar();
    } else { // Tablet layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer_tablet);
        container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        setupFloatingActionButton();
        setUpToolbar();
    }

    if (mNavigationDrawerFragment == null) {
        // Instantiate the NavigationDrawer
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

        if (drawerLayout != null) {
            // Set up the drawer.
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                    R.id.navigation_drawer,
                    drawerLayout);
        }
    }

    // Instantiate prospectListFragment and corresponding layout for UI control if device is a tablet
    if (Ufp.getIsTablet()) {
        prospectListFragment = (ProspectListFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.prospects_list);
        prospectListFragmentLayout = prospectListFragment.getView();
    }
```

**LogCat**

```
    09-07 15:48:51.644 24077-24077/com.marketamerica.android.unfranchiseprospecting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.marketamerica.android.unfranchiseprospecting, PID: 24077
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.marketamerica.android.unfranchiseprospecting/com.marketamerica.android.unfranchiseprospecting.activities.NavDrawer}: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.res.Resources.newTheme()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.res.Resources.newTheme()' on a null object reference
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:134)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:85)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme(AppCompatActivity.java:86)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```